# Not able to login for Epic game Launcher through Google account

Tags: login, launcher, games, default-browser

I have Ubuntu LTS 22.04.3 version. I am trying to login for Epic game launcher application, but the default browser is not getting launched when i select any login option like Google, Facebook or any other option. Please help that how can i solve this problem? for other application default browser is getting launch properly.

Comment: I remember this happening sometime ago ... However, IIRC there should be an option to copy some token/string from another logged-in account in the actual web-browser ... i.e. login in the browser and then copy that token/string and paste it in the Epic Game Launcher and then you'll login there as well.